# Property xxx does not exist .... when using each

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have an object with this structure:

```
"properties": {
        "Design_definition": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "File name of the tsv file with header names: sample,reference,fwd_pair,rev_pair",
            "default": "design.tsv",
            "format": "file-path",
            "mimetype": "tsv"
        },
        "Threshold": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "Minimum value a score must have",
            "default": 0.85
        },
        "Taxonomical_domain": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Select the taxonomical domain of your organism",
            "enum": ["archaea", "bacteria", "eukaryota"],
            "default": "bacteria"
        },
        "Sensitive_calculation": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "description": "Calculation takes longer if selected"
        },...
```

I now try to parse over it and enter some values which are not in every property, like:

```
{#each Object.entries(currentWorkflow.item)  as [name, item]}
    <div>

        <span   style='margin-right:1.25em' title={item.description }  use:tooltip> {name}: </span> 
        <span> {item}  </span>
        {#if item.type === 'string' && item.format === 'file-path' }
        test    
        {/if} 
    </div>
{/each}
```

**Error:** Property 'format' does not exist on type '{ type: string; description: string; default: string; format: string; mimetype: string; } | { type: string; description: string; default: number; } | { type: string; description: string; enum: string[]; default: string; } | ... 9 more ... | { ...; }'.
Property 'format' does not exist on type '{ type: string; description: string; default: number; }'.js(2339)

Comment: That is (just) a type error. Where do the types come from? Are they defined manually or derived?

Comment: The error is explicit. You don't have 'format' properties on certain objects you're looping through.